# permission Apache PHP public_html

Tags: apache, unix, configuration

I'm newbie in the web development, and I'm trying to make a website. So, my website works fine on the server but not on my own (Apache). My sources are in ~/public_html/. The  problem is I don't have permissions on the sub/sub directory, I mean, when it's a directory, it works fine, when it's directory in a directory, it doesn't. (403 Forbidden). I don't change my default Apache configuration excluding for include mysql and php. 
All my directories have the same permissions. Maybe I need to configure something for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used this little script found at this link http://boomshadow.net/tech/fixes/fixperms-script/

**Fixperms – for one single user**

To use the fixperms script, simply log into your server as root, wget the file from our server, then run it. Type in the cPanel username and it will run only for that particular account.

It does not matter which directory you are in when you run fixperms. You can be in the user’s home directory, the server root, etc. The script will not affect anything outside of the particular user’s folder.

**Should be done in SSH**

root@example [~]# wget boomshadow.net/tools-utils/fixperms.sh

root@example [~]# sh ./fixperms.sh -a USER-NAME

**Fixperms – for all of the users**

If you would like fix the permissions for every user on your cPanel server, simply use the ‘-all’ option:

root@example [~]# wget boomshadow.net/tools-utils/fixperms.sh

root@example [~]#sh ./fixperms.sh -all